# Receiving error of "The type or namespace name 'LayoutsPageBase' could not be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

To give you entire perspective, I am trying to create a custom ribbon in SharePoint. For that I am following this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606%28v=office.14%29.aspx). I created the required feature and was able to deploy and test it with simple JavaScript alert. Now I am trying to call an ASPX page on click of ribbon button.

For that I created an Application Page in my project. But in the code behind file of ASP.NET page I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'LayoutsPageBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CustomRibbonButton\CustomRibbonButton\Layouts\CustomRibbonButton\ApplicationPage1.aspx.cs
```

I have imported (I hope thats what you call it in C#) `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` with statement `using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;`

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7125717/1047998) on StackOverflow I was able to figure that `LayoutsPageBase` class is not available in sandbox solutions (with path as `\UserCode\assemblies`).

So in my project I went to `References > Microsoft.SharePoint`, right-clicked on it to view its Properties. Its `Path` in Properties window is shown as `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`.

What can be the reason for this error and how can it be solved?

Comment: @RobH: I selected Farm solution. The path `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` is of farm solution, right? How can I check after creating solution that it is a sandbox or farm solution?

Comment: @RobH: I checked the Sandboxed Solution as you said and it was set to true. Thanks! But the path of `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` still confuses me.

Comment: Have you got it working now?

Comment: @RobH: Yes, but unsure of what should I do with this questio now. Shaould I mark it as duplicate or delete it altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name ‘LayoutsPageBase’ does not exist in the namespace ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125717/the-type-or-namespace-name-layoutspagebase-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-mi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check whether or not a SharePoint project is Sandboxed by right clicking the project in Solution Explorer and viewing the properies.

There is a true/false property called `Sandboxed Solution`.